# ec2-describe-images -o self -o amazon returns nothing

Tags: amazon-ec2

I just want to install the ec2-api-tools. So I follows the instructions on this links
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide

But when I give `ec2-describe-images -o self -o amazon` on the command line, it returns nothing.There is no error. It just waits like waiting for an input. What is the wrong I have done?

Thanks for helps.

Comment: did you try following the official amazon guides instead?

Comment: I am also facing same error ! if it's not recognizing your credentials but getting out put for $ aws ec2 describe-images --executable-users all --filters "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs"  | wc -l
143186
ie is it that aws cli is configured with proper credentials  ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have set environment variable correctly (and set appropriate privilege, I remember it's `chmod 400`). E.g.

```
$ export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=/PATH/TO/PK/pk-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pem
$ export EC2_CERT=/PATH/TO/CERT/cert-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pem
```

Also, Apart from this your command looks good. Also, keep in mind that *owner* amazon has lots of AMIs listed.. so it may not be super quick to see the result.. you might need to wait a couple to 10s of seconds.

Please read these:

1. [Installing Amazon EC2 Command Line Tools](http://cloudarchitect.posterous.com/the-ec2-api-tools)
2. [Latest CLI reference to Amazon API Command Line](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/index.html?ApiReference-cmd-DescribeImages.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not recognizing your credentials.  Double check those settings.